# RecyclerView Item Size changing while scrolling every time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I have a chat RecyclerView, and I want the ImageView to wrap different sizes. When the view loads for the first time it works fine, but on scroll the sizes changes. If possible i want to fit different sizes without losing control of width and height.

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sentContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/sentImgL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sent_img_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/receivedImgCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sentImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="250dp"
                android:maxHeight="350dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:src="@drawable/me_p" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dateSeenImgS"
                android:text="@string/todo"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Make   android:layout_width="match_parent" for each element behalf of   android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb -- Unfortunately, it doesn't work right, and the sizes still change every time you scroll.

Comment: This is the layout of a single ViewHolder? Can you show more code e.g. your Adapter and loading the image into the ImageView. Also why do you have a single ConstraintLayout inside a single ConstraintLayout. Couldn't you lose one of them?

Comment: Better use Glide or Picasso to load, or just resize the images to the specific size before displaying them in ImageView.

Comment: I believe case of the size changing it will keep changing when you scroll since you have the major max width and height. here your code                 android:maxWidth="250dp"
android:maxHeight="350dp". If you try to have this fix size. that it will not change the size.

Answer (score 0):

Override this two methods inside your RecyclerAdapter.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: What getItemViewType() returns?